# Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to scroll vertical in my App but if I change it so Axis.vertical flutter gives me this error.
Here is my home_screen

```
import 'package:fliphy/screens/base_screen/base_screen.dart';
import 'package:fliphy/screens/base_screen/video_screen.dart';
import 'package:fliphy/services/giphy_client/giphy_client.dart';
import 'package:fliphy/services/giphy_client/models/popular_video_response.dart';
import 'package:fliphy/widgets/video_thumb.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return BaseScreen(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Popular Videos",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: VideoList(),
              )
            ],
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          ),
          height: 250,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}


class VideoList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return VideoListState();
  }
}

class VideoListState extends State<VideoList> {
  PopularVideoResponse _popularVideoResponse;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final client = GiphyClient(apiKey: "censored");
    client.getPopularVideos().then((videoResponse) {
      setState(() {
        _popularVideoResponse = videoResponse;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_popularVideoResponse == null) {
      return Container();
    }
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: this._popularVideoResponse.data.map((v) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VideoScreen(v.images.originalMp4.mp4, v.title)));
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: VideoThumb(v.images.originalMp4.mp4, false),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(child: Container()),
                    Container(
                      child: Text(v.title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black45),
                      height: 20,
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
These invalid constraints were provided to RenderStack's layout() function by
the following
function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
  RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout
  (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:277:14)
The offending constraints were:
  BoxConstraints(w=370.0, h=Infinity)

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Container
  Container:file:///Users/abduelhamit/dev/fliphy/lib/screens/base_screen/home
  _screen.dart:79:26

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure>.throwError
(package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:517:9)
#1      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:561:11)
#2      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid
(package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:565:6)
#3      RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1758:24)
#4      RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:277:14)
#5      RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#7      _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1388:11)
#8      RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#9      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#10     RenderStack._computeSize
(package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:570:43)
#11     RenderStack.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:597:12)
#12     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#13     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:277:14)
#14     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#15     RenderPadding.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:233:12)
#16     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#18     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#19     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#20     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#22     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#23     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#24     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#25     RenderSliverList.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:213:28)
#26     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#27     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
#28     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:371:11)
#29     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#30     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence
(package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
#31     RenderViewport._attemptLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1580:12)
#32     RenderViewport.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1489:20)
#33     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#34     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#35     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#37     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#38     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#39     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#40     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#41     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#42     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#43     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#44     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#45     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#46     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#47     RenderFlex._computeSizes
(package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:896:45)
#48     RenderFlex.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#49     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#50     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:277:14)
#51     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#52     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#53     RenderFlex._computeSizes
(package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
#54     RenderFlex.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#55     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#56     RenderPadding.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:233:12)
#57     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#59     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#60     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#61     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1388:11)
#62     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#63     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#64     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#65     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#66     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#68     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#69     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild
(package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#70     RenderStack._computeSize
(package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:570:43)
#71     RenderStack.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:597:12)
#72     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#73     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#74     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#75     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#76     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#77     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#78     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#79     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#80     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#81     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#82     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#83     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#84     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#85     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#86     RenderOffstage.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3422:13)
#87     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#88     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#89     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#90     _RenderTheatre.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:745:15)
#91     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#92     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#93     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#94     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#95     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#96     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#97     RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#98     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#99     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#100    RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#101    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#102    RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#103    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#104    RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#105    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#106    RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#107    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#108    RenderObject.layout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#109    RenderView.performLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:165:14)
#110    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1713:7)
#111    PipelineOwner.flushLayout
(package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:885:18)
#112    RendererBinding.drawFrame
(package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:453:19)
#113    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
(package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#114    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#115    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1143:15)
#116    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1080:9)
#117    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:863:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and
dart:async-patch)

The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
RenderConstrainedBox#da627 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
  creator: ConstrainedBox ← Container ← ClipRRect ← Stack ← ConstrainedBox ←
  Padding ← Container ←
    Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ←
    RepaintBoundary ← ⋯
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=370.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(biggest)
This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
    child: RenderStack#8f0ab NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
    NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
      child 1: RenderConstrainedBox#8c29e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
      NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        child: RenderDecoratedBox#0d0bd NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
      child 2: _RenderColoredBox#f960e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
      NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        child: RenderClipRRect#cbafb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
        NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
          child: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#64c96 NEEDS-LAYOUT
          NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            child: RenderDecoratedBox#96b41 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
═══════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderConstrainedBox#da627 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderClipRRect#ce8d6 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#0d425
relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderConstrainedBox#e96b3 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#c6333
relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderPointerListener#d9f05 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#0af6a relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderRepaintBoundary#0867c relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown:
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed
assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.

Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value

Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value

Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value

Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
Performing hot reload...
Reloaded 1 of 875 libraries in 526ms.

Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderConstrainedBox#da627 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderClipRRect#ce8d6 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#0d425
relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderConstrainedBox#e96b3 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#c6333
relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderPointerListener#d9f05 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#0af6a relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
RenderRepaintBoundary#0867c relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT

Another exception was thrown:
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed
assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.

Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value

Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value

Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
```

Scrolling horizontal is not a problem see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtZ2d.png). Everything is ok with the app, its my first app but I can't change it to a Column or a list to scroll vertical. Everywhere is a Column but I can't change it. If u need more Code tell me I will edit it in, that's not a problem.

```
        Container(
          height: 500,
         color: Colors.blue,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Popular Videos",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Container(
                child: VideoList(),
                color: Colors.green,
                height: 300,

              ),
```

[Some color for the Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB6GN.jpg)If I change it to vertical, same problem

Comment: try giving height to your `Container` and removing `Expanded(child: Container()),` from your `Column`

Comment: Make nullable like `PopularVideoResponse? _popularVideoResponse;` and now you may find height errors.

Comment: Ty fo your response guys, I am a beginner and not very good and @ritikkumarsrivastava I tried to do that you gave me a good Idea but I couldn't do it. I tried to make the Container bigger and changed my code Axis.vertical to horizontal and there is still an error :/

Comment: Ty @YeasinSheikh I can't do it this way because if I update flutter in this project to a newer version I need to change like everything in my Json page I had this problem earlier and could only solve my problem with downgrade my project. Because I can't change much in JSON because I don't understand everything in there

Comment: That is how its now look at my Edit (I added some Color for you for the Container)